# GET Запросы. Получение данных

Tags: php, json

Есть запрос [api.bus62.ru/api7/?cm=gsf&cd=yakutsk&sr=mob&f=json&sid=129&type=0&lim=80&deep=4&devid=1439865001](http://api.bus62.ru/api7/?cm=gsf&cd=yakutsk&sr=mob&f=json&sid=129&type=0&lim=80&deep=4&devid=1439865001)

```js
{
"forecast": [
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "4",
"arrTime": "94",
"lastStation": "Столичный рынок",
"whereGo": "Газпром"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "41",
"arrTime": "128",
"lastStation": "Якутская",
"whereGo": "Магазин Успех"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "14",
"arrTime": "138",
"lastStation": "Якутская",
"whereGo": "Тэкки Одулока"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "20",
"arrTime": "156",
"lastStation": "Якутская",
"whereGo": "Мелиорация"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "25",
"arrTime": "217",
"lastStation": "Профлицей",
"whereGo": "2-я дамба"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "4",
"arrTime": "271",
"lastStation": "Архив",
"whereGo": "Газпром"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "4",
"arrTime": "409",
"lastStation": "Банковская",
"whereGo": "Газпром"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "41",
"arrTime": "461",
"lastStation": "8 Марта",
"whereGo": "Магазин Успех"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "4",
"arrTime": "538",
"lastStation": "ФСБ",
"whereGo": "Газпром"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "109",
"arrTime": "650",
"lastStation": "ФСБ",
"whereGo": "Захаровка"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "14",
"arrTime": "668",
"lastStation": "ФСБ",
"whereGo": "Тэкки Одулока"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "25",
"arrTime": "698",
"lastStation": "Новинка",
"whereGo": "2-я дамба"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "20",
"arrTime": "754",
"lastStation": "Кинотеатр Центральный",
"whereGo": "Мелиорация"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "14",
"arrTime": "868",
"lastStation": "Кинотеатр Центральный",
"whereGo": "Тэкки Одулока"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "41",
"arrTime": "968",
"lastStation": "Глазная больница",
"whereGo": "Магазин Успех"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "20",
"arrTime": "1000",
"lastStation": "Пл. Ленина",
"whereGo": "Мелиорация"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "4",
"arrTime": "1002",
"lastStation": "Пл. Ленина",
"whereGo": "Газпром"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "25",
"arrTime": "1212",
"lastStation": "Областная больница",
"whereGo": "2-я дамба"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "4",
"arrTime": "1222",
"lastStation": "Кинотеатр Лена",
"whereGo": "Газпром"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "20",
"arrTime": "1336",
"lastStation": "Тургенева",
"whereGo": "Мелиорация"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "14",
"arrTime": "1356",
"lastStation": "Школа №3",
"whereGo": "Тэкки Одулока"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "41",
"arrTime": "1420",
"lastStation": "Стадион Туймаада",
"whereGo": "Магазин Успех"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "4",
"arrTime": "1483",
"lastStation": "Байкалова",
"whereGo": "Газпром"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "14",
"arrTime": "1590",
"lastStation": "Ипподром",
"whereGo": "Тэкки Одулока"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "20",
"arrTime": "1711",
"lastStation": "Магазин В десятку",
"whereGo": "Мелиорация"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "14",
"arrTime": "1908",
"lastStation": "ЯПАТП",
"whereGo": "Тэкки Одулока"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "41",
"arrTime": "1936",
"lastStation": "Пл. Дружбы",
"whereGo": "Магазин Успех"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "25",
"arrTime": "1972",
"lastStation": "Русский театр",
"whereGo": "2-я дамба"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "41",
"arrTime": "2171",
"lastStation": "ЯГУ",
"whereGo": "Магазин Успех"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "14",
"arrTime": "2294",
"lastStation": "Орхидея",
"whereGo": "Тэкки Одулока"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "25",
"arrTime": "2411",
"lastStation": "Славяне",
"whereGo": "2-я дамба"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "41",
"arrTime": "2621",
"lastStation": "Шевченко",
"whereGo": "Магазин Успех"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "25",
"arrTime": "3076",
"lastStation": "Ильменская",
"whereGo": "2-я дамба"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "41",
"arrTime": "3097",
"lastStation": "Ильменская",
"whereGo": "Магазин Успех"
},
  {
"type": "А",
"num": "41",
"arrTime": "3574",
"lastStation": "Горняк",
"whereGo": "Магазин Успех"
}
],
}
```

Как из этого вывести значения num,arrtime,lastStation,whereGo на страницу сайта например.

Comment: вы определитесь, на чем вывести на js или на php. отредактируйте свой вопрос ([edit]) и укажите только нужные тэги. `php, json` или `js, json`, остальное тут мусор. Приведите код как вы получаете данные и планируете выводить их.

Comment: Спасибо, подправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Устанавливаем параметр, чтобы curl возвращал данные, вместо того, чтобы выводить их в браузер.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return json_decode($data);
    }
    $json = file_get_contents_curl('http://api.bus62.ru/api7/?cm=gsf&cd=yakutsk&sr=mob&f=json&sid=129&type=0&lim=80&deep=4&devid=1439865001');
    foreach($json->forecast as $v){
      echo $v->num.'<br>'.$v->arrTime.'<br>'.$v->lastStation.'<br>'.$v->whereGo .'<br>';
      echo '------------<br>';
    }
```

Как то так.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Создайте одну функцию, с которым в дальнейшем сможете отправлять все запросы

```
function sendRequest($url, $params = null, $method = 'GET'){
    if (!empty ($url))
    {
        $handler = curl_init ($url);

        $options = [
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER          => true,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION          => true,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST           => $method,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT          => 0,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST          => false,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER          => false,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT                 => 0,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING                => true,
        ];

        if (in_array ($method, ['POST']))
        {
            if ($method == 'POST') $options[CURLOPT_POST] = true;
            $options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = http_build_query ($params);
        }

        curl_setopt_array($handler, $options);
        $result = curl_exec ($handler);
        curl_close ($handler);
        return json_decode($result);
    }
    return false;
}
```

а дальше сделайте просто запрос в нужном месте

GET

```
$obj = sendRequest('http://api.bus62.ru/api7/?cm=gsf&cd=yakutsk&sr=mob&f=json&sid=129&type=0&lim=80&deep=4&devid=1439865001');
```

POST

```
$obj = sendRequest('URL', ['key'=>'val','key1'=>'val1'], 'POST');
```